# Getting decorated methods of a given class from within that class

Tags: python

Given a class and a set of its methods - how can you determine from within that class which methods have been decorated with a certain decorator?

My goal is to basically get the actual values of the methods that are decorated, so something like:

```
class A():
    def get_values(self):
      ... 
      # returned {'a-special-name': 1, 'b': 2}


    @my_dec('a-special-name')  # Ideally be able to also put optional name
    def a(self):
      return 1

    @my_dec
    def b(self):
      return 2
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Edit: this should also work on parent classes, that is, if `A` is a subclass of:

```
class B():
    @my_dec
    def c(self):
        return 3
```

then `get_values()` of `A` instance should return `{'a-special-name': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}` (order is irrelevant of course)

Edit: class based decorator that works but not with inheritance. Any idea how to make it work with inheritance but without having to decorate the class itself?

```
class my_dec(object):
    def __init__(self, func, name=None):
        self.func = func
        self.name = name or func.__name__
        self.func._some_flag = True

    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self.func(instance)
```

Comment: Unless the decorator leaves some trace on the decorated function itself (e.g. by setting a property on the function object) or some other side effect you can inspect, that's going to be hard.

Comment: I do realise it's not an easy task. Using the decorator would make my life much easier in this particular project, but all that matters is that somehow the methods are flagged and retrieved with the `get_values` method. Maybe a class wide private `_to_value` dictionary (method: desired_name)? But how to insert the method & name into it nicely...

Comment: To be clear: you are entirely in charge of both the decorator and the class? I.e. you're not trying to use some existing decorator and detect it, but you can define what the decorator does yourself?

Comment: Yes, `my_dec` is to be designed after it is determined whether something like this is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define the decorator yourself, then simply have it "mark" the method object in some way:

```
def my_dec(method):
    method._this_be_decorated = True
    return method
```

The class can then look for those marked methods; something like:

```
from inspect import isfunction

class A:
    def get_values(self):
        return filter(lambda i: isfunction(i) and hasattr(i, '_this_be_decorated'), 
                      vars(type(self)).values())
```

This will return an iterable of function objects which you can process further as needed.

Comment: This is interesting, but it does not seem to work with methods declared in parent classes. That is, if `class A` is a subclass of `B` and `B` has a method decorated, then I need also those values in `A(some_args_and_kwargs).get_values()`

Comment: Yes, since inheritance works by traversing up the inheritance chain *when attempting to access a specific property*, this won't work. You'll have to iterate the parent class(es) in `get_value` additionally.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_dec(name):
    if callable(name):
        # name is callable – take its name
        func = name # no make the code more readable
        func.special_name = func.__name__
        return func
    else:
        # name is the name to give – add an inner layer of functions
        def inner(function_object):
            function_object.special_name = name
            return function_object
        return inner

class A():
    def get_values(self):
        # return a dict of special name to call result mapping for every class member that has a special_name.
        return {func.special_name: func(self) for func in self.__class__.__dict__.values() if hasattr(func, 'special_name')}
      # returned {'a-special-name': 1, 'b': 2}
    @my_dec('a-special-name')  # Ideally be able to also put optional name
    def a(self):
      return 1
    @my_dec
    def b(self):
      return 2
    def no_dec(self):
      return 42
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As deceze mentions, decorators can do whatever they want so there's no reliable generic answer. If you "own" the decorator you can add special properties to it's return value ie (Q&D py2.7 example):

```
def mydec(name=''):
    # py27 hack - for py3 you want nonlocal instead
    n = [name]

    def innerdec(func):
        # py27 hack - for py3 you want nonlocal instead
        name = n[0] or func.__name__
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            print("in mydec.wrapper for {}".format(name))
            return func(*args, **kw)
        wrapper.ismydec = True # so we know this is decorated by mydec
        wrapper.func = func # so we can get the original func
        wrapper.name = name
        return wrapper
    return innerdec

def collect_dec(cls):
      decorated = {}
      for attname in dir(cls):
          obj = getattr(cls, attname)
          if getattr(obj, "ismydec", False):
              decorated[obj.name] = obj.func
      cls._decorated_funcs = decorated
      return cls

@collect_dec
class A():
    def get_values(self):
        return {
            name:func(self) for name, func in self._decorated_funcs.items()
            }

    @mydec('a-special-name')  # Ideally be able to also put optional name
    def a(self):
      return 1

    @mydec() # no name
    def b(self):
      return 2


a = A()
print(a.get_values())
```

Which outputs:

```
{'a-special-name': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Is there a way to collect the decorators directly in the class, even if it inherits methods of parents, without decorating the class itself? I've edited my original question to also include the inheritance need.

Comment: @emihir0 yes of course, cf my answer. I used a class decorator to avoid doing the whole collection again and again but the same code would work as well in the `get_values()` method.